# Is there any way to set a node to be shown in 2 menus?

Tags: routes

I have a node **"my-node"** which I set to be shown in the **Main Menu** so far so good.

I created another menu: "My Menu".

Is there any way to show **my-node** in both menu: **Main Menu** and **My Menu**

If I edit the node and go under Menu settings it allows me to choose **just 1 Parent item**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Multiple Node Menu](http://drupal.org/project/multiple_node_menu/) module

> This module modifies the "Menu settings" in standard node editing form
>   to allow managing multiple menu links to a node.